# Is the PEP proxy service ready to be used to secure orion context broker?

Tags: fiware-orion

If yes, I have the following questions:

1. After the pep proxy service is started up, should the context broker also be restarted (which I cannot)?
2. Should the IM and AM server be started up separately?
3. If I use an CEP instance to send events to the Orion Context Broker,  is there any way to specify that the orion broker is secured? How to create users for the PEP proxy server? or is there any way for an cep instance to bypass the authentication and authorisation to Orion Context Broker?

Comment: By CEP do you mean Proton CEP?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning 1: conceptually, PEP Proxies should be transparent to the components they are protecting, so you shouldn't have to make changes or restart your Context Broker.

Concerning 2: if by "started up separately" you mean they are different processes, independent from the PEP proxy, and should be started up separately, yes they are: they are independent of the use of a PEP proxy; it will be the PEP who contact both systems to do its job. If with "separately" you mean "in different machines", that's not really needed, you can have your own security machine with all the components, although that's not advisable.

Your third question will depend on what CEP are you going to use, as @fgalan pointed out. If the CEP supports the use of fiware authorization mechanisms, you can integrate it with the PEP-protected CB; if it does not, but your system doesn't require the users to directly interact with the CEP you can establish a secure connection between the Context Broker and the CEP independently (by using Security Groups or firewall rules) thus bypassing the PEP protection for your system's internal components (by using the secured internal ports, instead of the public ones).

Hope this solves some of your doubts.